# Get content from ubuntu-latest to a new branch on GitHub

Tags: github-actions

I got into actions and ran into a problem. I need to get a project in ubuntu-latest, in this project I need to go to the folder and transfer the received contents of the folder to another GitHub branch.

[manual/gh](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh)

I tried to find the right command, but I couldn't

I don't want to work directly with git and I need the right solution.

Comment: To go into a folder from the repository in your workflow, you need to use the [action/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout). From there, you'll be able to use `cd` commands to navigate between your folders, and even perform `git` operations if you want to create another branch and push some code to it.